# How to do calculation with values in two instances?

Tags: c++, class, instance

We are asked to create two instances in the main function and do calculations, but I have no idea and there is always error message...
This is Complex.h

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstring>
#include <fstream>
#include <ctime>

class Complex
 {
   private:
   int real1,real2;
   double imag1,imag2;

   public:
   /*Complex();
   ~Complex(){  };*/
   void setReal(int newreal);/*setter function*/
   void setImag(double newimag);

   int getReal();/*getter function*/
   double getImag();

    void printcom(int real1, double imag1, int real2, double imag2);/*print the entered      values in mathematical form of complex number*/

   void Conjugate(int real1, double imag1, int real2, double imag2);/*calculations for complex number*/
   void Add(int real1, double imag1, int real2, double imag2);
   void Subtract(int real1, double imag1, int real2, double imag2);
   void Multiply(int real1, double imag1, int real2, double imag2);

 };
```

The complex.cpp is too long so I don't show it here, and it worked.

Then is the main testing function: testcomplex.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstring>
#include <fstream>
#include <ctime>
#include "Complex.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    Complex a,z,c;
    int real;
    double imag;

    cout << "The real part of the first complex number: "<<endl;
    cin >> real;
    a.setReal(real);
    cout << "The imaginary part of the first complex number: "<<endl;
    cin >> imag;
    a.setImag(imag);
    cout << "The real part of the second complex number: "<<endl;
    cin >> real;
    z.setReal(real);
    cout << "The imaginary part of the second complex number: "<<endl;
    cin >> imag;
    z.setImag(imag);

    c.printcom(a.real1,a.imag1,z.real1,imag1);
    c.Conjugate(a.real1,a.imag1,z.real1,imag1);
    c.Add(a.real1,a.imag1,z.real1,imag1);
    c.Subtract(a.real1,a.imag1,z.real1,imag1);
    c.Multiply(a.real1,a.imag1,z.real1,imag1);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This is kind of quiz or something? Why did not you show this `error message`?

Comment: @PiotrNycz I changed the private to real and imag, and now it is returning "complex::real is private, things like that.

Comment: Then cite this error message in your question and I bet you will receive answers explaining why you cannot use private member variables outside the class definition (main in this case).

Answer (score 1):

There is clear written in your assignment that "***We are asked to create two instances in the main function and do calculations***"

It means that class Complex should be written to define only one complex number. So how a complex number can have two real and imaginary parts?
Thus instead of

```
class Complex
 {
   private:
   int real1,real2;
   double imag1,imag2;
```

there must be

```
class Complex
 {
   private:
   int real;
   double imag;
```

Also I do not understand why real part of the class has type `int` while imagenary has type `double`.

Also member functions are declared incorrectly.  for example function printcom should be declared as

```
void printcom() const;
```

or function Add should be declared either as a member function as

```
const Complex Add( const Complex &rhs ) const;
```

as a non-member function

```
const Complex Add( const Complex &lhs, const Complex &rhs );
```

Answer (score 0):

each instance of Complex class must save 1 real part and 1 imaginary part.
so when you wanna add + two complex number like this:
z = a + b
you need to declare 3 complex that each of those has a real and imaginary part. But if you wanna save 2 complex number in each instance of your Complex class, your codes are correct , just you need 2 setReal and 2 setImag method like this:

```
void setReal1(int n)
{
    real1=n;
}
void setReal2(int n)
{
    real2=n;
}
void setImag1(double n)
{
        imag1=n;
}
void setImag2(double n)
{
        imag2=n;
}
```